# How to round of decimal values in C++

Tags: c++, rounding

With a function, I'm getting these values.. 0.07, 0.038, 0.072, 0.078. Now, I'm trying to apply round of to these values so that they should return like this.
`round(val, decimal_place)`. So that, 0.038 value should return as 0 and rest should come as 0.1. (I can do it using an if condition like limiting with <0.5>. But, want to know. Is there any such function is there in C++ which limit decimal places below 0.5.
It's there in VB by doing like this I think. `roundof(value, decimal_place)`.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14369673/round-double-to-3-points-decimal

Comment: It is only possible on output (e.g. output a value to three decimal places or to three significant figures).   A floating point variable cannot represent all multiples or powers of `0.1` precisely.   The reason is that floating point variables (with a base-2 aka binary mantissa) can only represent fractional values that are the sum of negative powers of 2.   So `0.1`  or `0.3` (decimal) cannot be exactly represented, but `0.5` and `0.25` (which are negative powers of 2) and `0.75` (which is a finite sum of negative powers of 2) can be.

Answer (score 1):

You can use setprecision() to limit the decimal place on floating point numbers.

```
var = 1.0 / 3.0; // returns 0.33333333...

cout << fixed << setprecision(1) << var; // returns 0.3
```